# My grid system is breaking while screen width getting shrinked HTML bootsrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Why my row getting second line, while shrinkering the width.

Here is the screen shot.

I am using bootstrap 5 for this, and dont know how to fix it, here is my code.

[How it is right now ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWLfz.png)

Here is the screenshot how I want this to look like on mobiles.

[How this has to look like Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsMyD.png)

```
<div class="container-fluid fixed-bottom " style="margin-bottom: 16px;">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col" >
      <div class="text-center bottomElement">
        <img class="img-fluid bottomIcon" src="/assets/business.png" style="max-width:56px;" />
        <p class="bottomText"  style="color: white;">Business</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="text-center bottomElement">
        <img class="img-fluid bottomIcon" src="/assets/calculator.png" style="max-width:56px;" />
        <p class="bottomText"  style="color: white;">Calculator</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="text-center bottomElement">
        <img class="img-fluid bottomIcon" src="/assets/oogPermits.png" style="max-width:56px;" />
        <p class="bottomText"  style="color: white;">OOG Permits</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="text-center bottomElement">
        <img class="img-fluid bottomIcon" src="/assets/services.png" style="max-width:56px;" />
        <p class="bottomText"  style="color: white;">Services</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="text-center bottomElement">
        <img class="img-fluid bottomIcon" src="/assets/career.png" style="max-width:56px;" />
        <p class="bottomText" style="color: white;">Career</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using rows and columns, i recommend using the flexbox classes

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap justify-content-between">

  <div>
   <img class="img-fluid bottomIcon" src="/assets/business.png" style="max-width:56px;" />
   <p class="bottomText"  style="color: white;">Business</p>
  </div>

  <div>
   <img class="img-fluid bottomIcon" src="/assets/calculator.png" style="max-width:56px;" />
   <p class="bottomText"  style="color: white;">Calculator</p>
  </div>

  <div>
   <img class="img-fluid bottomIcon" src="/assets/oogPermits.png" style="max-width:56px;" />
   <p class="bottomText"  style="color: white;">OOG Permits</p>
  </div>

  <div>
   <img class="img-fluid bottomIcon" src="/assets/services.png" style="max-width:56px;" />
   <p class="bottomText"  style="color: white;">Services</p>
  </div>

  <div>
   <img class="img-fluid bottomIcon" src="/assets/career.png" style="max-width:56px;" />
   <p class="bottomText" style="color: white;">Career</p>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

Sure. You can add a class to the parent container and control the margin with css.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-nowrap justify-content-between main">
 ...
</div>
```

then in your css :

```
@media screen and (min-width:998px){
 .main {
  margin: 196px;
 }
}
```

Comment: This works fine if I would not add margins. When I add margins, this happens [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/Zlbhjrc). I need to add 196px margin for desktop. Thanks!

Comment: I've added another answer to your question :). Let me know if it works for you !

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can add a class to the parent container and control the margin with css.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-nowrap justify-content-between main">
 ...
</div>
```

then in your css :

```
@media screen and (min-width:998px){
 .main {
  margin: 196px;
 }
}
```